# Confusion with tensorflow's Sequential Dense Layers

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I'm working on a regression probem using Tensorflow, and have created two models with slight differences in their first Dense layer.

## The Models

```
# Create some regression data
X_regression = tf.range(0, 1000, 5)
y_regression = tf.range(100, 1100, 5) # Y = X+ 100

# Split regression data into training and test sets
X_reg_train = X_regression[:150]
X_reg_test = X_regression[150:]
y_reg_train = y_regression[:150]
y_reg_test = y_regression[150:]
```

**Model 1**

```
# Setup random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)


model_1_reg = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])


model_1_reg.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
                    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                    metrics=['mae'])

model_1_reg.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1), y_reg_train, epochs=100)
```

**Model 2**

```
# Setup random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)


model_2_reg = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, input_shape=(None, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])


model_2_reg.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
                    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                    metrics=['mae'])

model_2_reg.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1), y_reg_train, epochs=100)
```

I'm confused about whether I should add the `input_shape` or not. **Model 1**'s input shape becomes `(None, 1)` and **Model 2**'s input becomes `(None, None, 1)`.

Both of them run, but perform differently.

**Model 2** makes sense since we're inputting an array, but if I think about it, does that mean I only have a single node in the input layer? Since I'm giving it a whole ndarray instead of the instances it self. **Model 1** makes sense too since I want to give each number into it.

So, which one makes sense more? Or what case should I use each model for?
Also, for **model 2**'s fit why does doing

```
tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1)
```

for the X of

```
model_2_reg.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1), y_reg_train, epochs=100
```

work? I thought we're suppose to put it in as a batch or like an array of the data so it should be inside an `ndarray`?

Comment: Keras infers the input shape (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57871463/674487)). What do you mean with "Both of them run, but perform differently"? Also, note that stacking multiple `Dense` layers is equivalent to a single `Dense` layer; you should include non-linearities (e.g. ReLU) in the intermediate layers. Check [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/106900/14675) for details on this issue.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, okay. Should the input layer be `(none, 1)` or should it be `(1,)`? If I set `(none, 1)` it means that in the fit I'm only fitting in 1 instance of the data If i give an ndarray. However, if I set it as `(1,)`, that means that the ndarray of integers are treated as a batch, so I'm giving it multiple instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras expects the inputs $X$ to be batched, i.e., of shape $B\times D$ in your case (for a feed-forward NN), where $B$ is the batch size (by default is 32, which can be assigned in `model.fit(..., batch_size=xyz)`) and $D$  is the dimensionality of your data or, if you want, the number of features.

In your case, you have one feature and also both `X_regression` and `y_regression` are not batched, i.e., they have shape $(N,)$ instead of $(N,1)$. Therefore, by calling `tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)` or `x[:, tf.newaxis]` or even `tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1, 1))`, you can correctly reshape them.

At this point, you specify the correct input dimensionality in the Sequential model, by setting `input_shape=(1,)` in the first dense layer. Note that `Dense` layers can also work on rank-3 tensors (i.e., of shape $B\times D\times K$) so if you write `input_shape=(None, 1)` you're adding another dimension which will be inferred at the first forward pass, i.e., `model(x)`. Basically, the batch dimension is implicit and you don't want to specify it.